# how I want the user id become static

Tags: cakephp, user-controls

I'm kind new to the cakephp and I want to know how to static the id where the id is on drop down or list. I have do hidden but its not enter the database. This is my coding:

*This is in the controller*

```
function add() {
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
   $this->Post->create();
   if ($this->Post->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
   }
  }
  $users = $this->Post->User->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('users'));
  $this->set('userid',$this->Auth->user('id'));
 }
```

*this coding is in the ctp*

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to not send the user id to the browser and back at all, since that opens the possibility of form tinkering and security breaches/invalid results. Just inject the user id into the data before saving:

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Post->create();

        // setting user id
        $this->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

        if ($this->Post->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }

    $users = $this->Post->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```